# How to use summarise to take the value of an variable that corresponds to the max. value of another variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

How to use summarise to take the value of a variable that corresponds to the maximum value of another variable?

**Data**: I have a simplified dataset below.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                 ID SBP DATE
                 1 90 20210102
                 1 106 20210111
                 2 80 20210513
                 2 87 20210513
                 2 88 20210413", header = TRUE)
```

I wish to take the value of `SBP`, which corresponds to the latest `DATE` (i.e. most recent measurement of systolic blood pressure). There may be ties, i.e. > 1 measurement within the same day (as shown in `ID=2`) and in such case, I would like to take the first line. Besides this, I may need to obtain other variables, like mean of SBP, no. of measurements of SBP etc. Hence, I would like to use only `summarise()`. Below is the desired output.

***Desired output***:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                 ID SBP 
                 1 106 
                 2 80", header = TRUE)
```

Here's what I have done previously.

**1)** Using `summarise` with `[` and `which.max`

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(SBP = SBP[which.max(DATE)])
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID   SBP
#  <int> <int>
#1     1   106
#2     2    80
```

**2)** Using `slice_max`

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice_max(DATE, with_ties = FALSE)
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID   SBP
#  <int> <int>
#1     1   106
#2     2    80
```

**3)** Using `summarise` with `last`

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(SBP = last(SBP, DATE))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#     ID   SBP
#  <int> <int>
#1     1   106
#2     2    87
```

I think (3) is ideal in terms of readability, but instead of taking the first line item, it takes the last line item (not what I want). If I use (2), I would have to use `mutate` to create other variables of interest (like number of measurements, mean etc.) before using `slice_max`. (1) would be confusing to other R readers/users.

My question: How can I write something like (3), but taking the first line, when there are ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use either 1) `arrange` + `distinct` or 2) `group_by` + `summarise` + `first` . The first approach is not as readable, but with big datasets it's actually more performant than using group by.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(ID, -DATE) %>% 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
#>   ID SBP     DATE
#> 1  1 106 20210111
#> 2  2  80 20210513
```

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(
    SBP = first(SBP, -DATE)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      ID   SBP
#> * <int> <int>
#> 1     1   106
#> 2     2    80
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Does the `-DATE` in both cases similar to `desc(DATE)`?

Comment: yep, should be similar :)